# how remove the array object index in json_encode using php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have two different arrays

```
$arr1=Array ( 'latitude' => 9.9252007, 'longitude' => 78.1197754, 'title' => 'Madurai' ) ;
$arr2=Array ( 'latitude' => 9.2323, 'longitude' => 78.23233, 'title' => 'Peraiyur' ) ;
```

i need to combine the both arrays into single and need to convert into json by json_encode, so my code is here to merge the array and parsed into json

```
$obj['markers']=(object) array( $arr1, $arr2 );

echo json_encode($obj);
```

the output is follows

```
 {"markers":
 {"0":{"latitude":9.9252007,"longitude":78.1197754,"title":"Madurai"},
  "1":{"latitude":9.2323,"longitude":78.23233,"title":"Peraiyur"}} }
```

but i need it to be like follow

> ```
> {"markers":[
>   { "latitude":9.9252007, "longitude":78.1197754, "title":"Madurai"  },
>   { "latitude":9.2323, "longitude":78.23233, "title":"Peraiyur" }
> ]}
> ```

how to remove them?

Comment: Hey, why the down vote here?? can yo explain ?

Comment: Why would you create the `$new_Arr` then...anyway, you may simply try `json_encode(array("markers"=>array($arr1,$arr2)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why casting into `object`? If you just remove the `(object)` casting it will be done!

```
$obj['markers']=array( $arr1, $arr2 );
```

result:

```
{"markers":[{"latitude":9.9252007,"longitude":78.1197754,"title":"Madurai"},{"latitude":9.2323,"longitude":78.23233,"title":"Peraiyur"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj['markers']=array( $arr1, $arr2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This object:

```
{"markers":[
  { "latitude":9.9252007, "longitude":78.1197754, "title":"Madurai"  },
  { "latitude":9.2323, "longitude":78.23233, "title":"Peraiyur" }
]}
```

is identical to:

```
print_r(json_encode(array('markers' => array($arr1, $arr2))));
```

Therefore, no need to do any additional complicated coding.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arr1=Array ( 'latitude' => 9.9252007, 'longitude' => 78.1197754, 'title' => 'Madurai' ) ;
$arr2=Array ( 'latitude' => 9.2323, 'longitude' => 78.23233, 'title' => 'Peraiyur' ) ;
$obj['markers']=array($arr1, $arr2);
echo json_encode($obj);
```

**output :**

```
{"markers":[{"latitude":9.9252007,"longitude":78.1197754,"title":"Madurai"},{"latitude":9.2323,"longitude":78.23233,"title":"Peraiyur"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it must be done:

```
$obj['markers']=array(
        array(
        'latitude' => $entity->getLat(),
        'longitude' => $entity->getLng(),
        'title' => $entity->getTitle(),
        )
    );
$json = json_encode($obj);
$response = new Response($json);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

It will produce this json file:

```
{"markers":[{"latitude":"36.80610237001900","longitude":"10.17517220741000","title":"Mon annonce"}]}
```